# error in SQL syntax (insert)

Tags: php, sql

Well I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,fb_title,fb_pic,fb_url,fb_desc) VALUES('', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''' at line 1
```

For the following code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO page(title,css,favicon,charset,keywords,author,desc,fb_title,fb_pic,fb_url,fb_desc)
VALUES('$title', '$css', '$favicon', '$charset', '$keywords', '$author', '$desc', '$fb_title', '$fb_pic', '$fb_url', '$fb_desc')";
```

Everything looks fine to me.. what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC is a reserved keyword. you should put it as `` `DESC` `` to escape it.

```
INSERT INTO page(title,css,favicon,charset,keywords,author,`desc`,fb_title,fb_pic,fb_url,fb_desc)
  VALUES('$title', '$css', '$favicon', '$charset', '$keywords', '$author', '$desc', '$fb_title', '$fb_pic', '$fb_url', '$fb_desc')
```

Comment: Same error :(
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''desc',fb_title,fb_pic,fb_url,fb_desc) VALUES('title', '/includes/style.css', '' at line 1

Comment: it´s backticks, not singlequotes. ` not '

Comment: @ImriPersiado its a backtick not single quote..

Comment: My bad, thanks for your help! I'll accept your answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

**`DESC`** is a reserved keyword and you cannot have that as a column else surround it using a  backtick operator .

Here..

```
$sql="INSERT INTO page(title,css,favicon,charset,keywords,author,desc,fb_t
                                                     ------------^
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add Backtic around `desc` because its a reserve word

```
INSERT INTO page(title,css,favicon,charset,keywords,author,`desc`,fb_title,fb_pic,fb_url,fb_desc)
VALUES('$title', '$css', '$favicon', '$charset', '$keywords', '$author', '$desc', '$fb_title', '$fb_pic', '$fb_url', '$fb_desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

desc is reserved keyword of mysql

```
$sql="INSERT INTO page(`title`, `css`, `favicon`, `charset`, `keywords`, `author`,`desc`,`fb_title`,`fb_pic`,`fb_url`,`fb_desc`)
VALUES('$title', '$css', '$favicon', '$charset', '$keywords', '$author', '$desc', '$fb_title', '$fb_pic', '$fb_url', '$fb_desc')";
```